I want to install 2 sump pumps to a single 1” discharge pipe. Is it possible without creating a bottleneck and damaging the pumps?
I want to install dual sump pumps to a single 1” discharge pipe.
Can it be done without creating a bottleneck and/or damaging the pumps?

1" is rather small for one sump pump, much less two.

See also: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/296046/18078

instal a check valve to prevent one pump droving the other

I’m definitely installing a check valve on each pump if it’s possible to do what I’m asking.

is one pump too slow or do you have a different reason to want this?

Too much water to pump.

you'll be helped by a using a fatter pipe in that case.

I will definitely do that. Thanks.

As you have not specified a model of sump pump, I looked up sump pump manual and took the first result I got. https://waynepumps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Sump_600002W-009-E_Web.pdf No endorsement implied.
While it does not detail "how small a pipe you can attach" both the 1/2 & 1/3 horsepower (quite small) pumps have 1-1/2" discharge piping connections.
A 1" pipe is 44% of the area of a 1-1/2" pipe, so connecting one pump to 1" pipe is already a significant restriction from the 1-1/2" they appear to be designed for. Connecting two pumps to a 1" pipe is thus reducing the area of the discharge pipe to 22% of the designed cross-sectional area.
While no specific pipe sizing guidelines are given in the linked manual, the output pipe is illustrated on page 5 as being the same size as the output (1-1/2") and multiple issues in the troubleshooting chart on pages 6 and 7 mention "restricted discharge" as a probable cause. Thus, building in a discharge restriction seems unlikely to be a good idea.

Thanks for your detailed response. I’ll change the discharge pipe to a 2” minimum.
